# Congruence question; please help.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Determine the largest integer $n$ which has at most three digits and equals the remainder when $n^2$ is divided by $1000$.

I've determined that the last digit can only be 1, 5, or 6, but if I try to continue, I meet some problems with $n^2$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  You mean like $625$?  Are you familiar with modular arithmetic?

Comment: Same method(s) as in the linked dupe, except choose the largest solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for $n$ such that $1000$ divides $n^2-n=n(n-1)$.

That means $8$ divides $n(n-1)$, and $125$ divides $n(n-1)$.

That means $8$ divides $n$ or $n-1$, and $125$ divides $n$ or $n-1$.

There aren't many numbers $n$ of at most three digits such that $125$ divides $n$ or $n-1$.

Look for ones such that also $8$ divides $n$ or $n-1$, and you'll find what you're looking for.